# Absolute position div don't overlays another's div child

Tags: html, css, z-index

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="avatar"></div>
  <div class="desc an-all"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="avatar"></div>
  <div class="desc an-all"></div>
</div>

.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper:hover .desc{
  opacity: 1;
}

.avatar{
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30;
}

.desc{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}

.an-all{
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```

I can't figure out why is this happening. I thought that a position element inside a parent with position relative only apply inside parent and outside is a different world.

Why when I hover the green box of the first wrapper div the red one don't overlay the second's wrapper div green box ? I want the red box to be under the green one when I hover

http://codepen.io/laxmana/pen/txKbF

Comment: On the link you've shared, it works perfectly fine. The red box is always under the green one. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: "when I hover the first green box the red one don't overlays" but yet "want the red box to be under the green" so which way is it supposed to be? Also, it seems to work, assuming you want red under green. Using FF.

Comment: Sorry for my English and my bad explanation. What I want is: When I hover the green box of the first wrapper div the red box to be under the first green box(the green box of first wrapper) BUT over the green box of the second wrapper div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you like this example:[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/yjzca8u8/)

It uses your same working code, but the wrapper divs are placed within a relative parent, and each are given their own z-index. This is how you can layer one on top of another. In a real world example, the divs may not be together (like a tooltip), and then you wouldn't need the additional parent. The parent is useful when the divs are together, and on the same level. Play around with the JSFiddle, and try different options with content.

In the original example, the reason the green divs were always on top, regardless of their html order, is because the red divs are absolutely positioned, and the 2 wrapper elements are on the same level within the parent.

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.wrapper:hover .desc {
    opacity: 1;
}
.relative-container {
    position:relative;
}
.top {
    z-index:10;
}
.bottom {
    z-index:9;
}
.avatar {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background: green;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 30;
}
.desc {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 20;
}
.an-all {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
    transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```

---

### Update

Here is an example with multiple display:inline-block divs. The trick is for the z-index to work, the divs *need to be siblings/on the same level as each other (this works for other elements too).* The first div in the row that needs to go on top gets the highest z-index, while the last div gets the lowest z-index.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/stgfchkz/)

Here is a great resource explaining the details on the z-index https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Note: In the second JSFiddle I used display:none on the red ".desc" dropdowns, and made them visible only when moused over by adding display:block; to ".wrapper:hover .desc". In your original code even though you don't see the red divs, when you hover over their invisible area it triggers them to show. By using display:none, they are truly not displayed in the page and therefore can't trigger the hover state. The trick is that display:block overwrites the display:none in the hover class, so they will show when the green buttons are hovered over.

This hides the red divs:

```
.desc {
    display:none;
```

This shows the red divs only when the green divs are hovered over:

```
.wrapper:hover .desc {
    display:block;
```

Comment: This will work with only two div wrappers but if I have an unknown number of wrappers as inline-block I can't know which one will be on top and which one below.

Comment: I added an example and description to the answer that uses multiple inline-block divs.

Answer (score 0):

Your `z-index` needs to change. Right now, both red boxes have an index lower than the green, which is why it appears beneath the second green box.

**Update**
Based on your comment, you want to have the green box both underlay the `avatar` class and overlay the same class below the `wrapper`. Because you're using classes alone, you can't have both actions. You could space the `wrappers` differently so you have the description still underlay the avatar and not overlap lower elements.

**CSS**

```
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;     /* Set this to auto to keep elements separate from one another */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.wrapper:hover .desc {
  opacity: 1;
}

.avatar{
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30;
}

.desc{
  position: relative; /* Keep it inside the document flow */
  top:-20px;          /* sets the overlap from the avatar class */
  left: 0;
  height: 250px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 20;        /* Displays below the avatar */
}

.an-all{
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s linear;
transition: all 0.3s linear;
}
```

## [Working pen](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/gCqDK)

Comment: Thanks for your response but I want a portion of the red box to be under the green box in the same wrapper div. So top has to be 50px;

Comment: You'll need to use relative positioning and some div id's then because you cannot have a portion of one element under a class and above a different element of the same class at the same time.

Comment: Thanks again but the layout has to be that way. The height don't have to contain the height of the .desc div. Is like when you hover somewhere and an info box appears.

Comment: The other problem this leads to, though, is that when I think I'm hovering on the second avatar, the first description pops up because of the way absolute positions change the document flow. Just trying to show other issues that come up with this particular use of positioning.